# How do you find your followers?

Tags: discussion

Don't judge, I'm new to this.
How do you find your followers in you profile? 
Can you see how many you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't Facebook or Twitter: the concept of 'followers' or following someone doesn't exist here.

You have the option of

- marking a question as a favourite (click the star below the vote count),
- marking certain tags as favourite (click 'Add a favourite tag' on the right of the 'Questions' page or edit favourite tags on Preferences tab of your 'Edit Profile...'),
- marking certain tags to be ignored (also in the Preferences section of 'Edit Profile...')

There's no option to mark a contributor.

Comment: `This isn't Facebook or Twitter`....thank the stars!

Comment: However the term *follower* does appear [when hovering tags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p47lz.png).

Answer (score 1):

[Airsick's answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2823/755) is correct that there's no official 'follow' feature in the StackExchange networks, so there's no way to see how many 'followers' you have (because you don't officially have any.)

Having said that, this issue has been discussed [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41483/271431) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57334/271431) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18978/271431) [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/271431) [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109525/271431).

The concise version is as follows:

---

**[SE is not a social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/271431)** and, thus, will not be implementing any concept of 'following' someone within SE itself.

---

Each user does have an RSS feed which can be accessed at:

http://SE-site-domain-here/feeds/user/user-id-here

You can find a user's ID by going to their user page and looking at the number in the address bar.

So, for example, if you want to follow your own RSS feed for Aviation.SE, it's:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/11914

There's no way to see who's looking at this, though.

---

[This guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/220601/blunderboy) has created [a Chrome extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites) to follow an SE user, which he discusses in [this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225503/271431). I haven't used it, though, so I can't see how well (or if) it works.